# printing sum of the list in tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

Hi i am trying to print the sum of the numbers that will be written in the entry boxes but I think there is a problem with changing list into int form. I keep getting this error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Entry'
```

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk() 
window.title=("card")
window.geometry('1500x100')
entries = []
def total():
    for entry in entries:
        global sum
        sum = sum + int(entry)
        e1.insert(0,sum)
    
for i in range(10):
    en = Entry(window)
    en.grid(row=1, column=0+i)
    entries.append(en)

b1=Button(window,text="dsf",command=total).grid(row=7,column=1)

e1=Entry(window).grid(row=20,column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dont use already reserved names, like `sum`. These are reserved to guarentee the functionality of python. BTW, you need to call the `entery.get()` method to get the content.

Comment: thank you for your comment but could you please correct my code for me? I tried to correct it but not sure how.. sorry

Comment: How about just `e1.insert(0, sum(int(e) for e in entries))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code have multiple issues,see code below.

```
import tkinter as tk #dont use wildcard imports to avoid name conflicts

window = tk.Tk() 
window.title=("card")
window.geometry('1500x100')
entries = []
def total():
    summa = 0 #dont use reserved names like sum or all
    for entry in entries: 
        summa += int(entry.get())#+entrys content as int
        e1.delete(0, 'end')#clear entry
        e1.insert(0,summa)
    
for i in range(3):
    en = tk.Entry(window)
    en.grid(row=1, column=0+i)
    entries.append(en)

b1=tk.Button(window,text="dsf",command=total)#split construction
b1.grid(row=7,column=1)#######################from geometry method

e1=tk.Entry(window)
e1.grid(row=20,column=2)

window.mainloop()
```